# I have a single class that I reuse in all my projects. Should I turn it into a library component?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a single class that I reuse in all my projects. Should I turn it into a library component? Is it worth making a single class a library or is it overkill?

EDIT: Two more reasons for making it a library:
1. I have 2 more additional components in my latest project and if this class is a component they will also be able to use it
2. I was thinking about adding an annotation-based addition to the class that will allow its clients to add annotations and use it with much less writing. This will require an additional class or a suite of classes and this will make it more component-worthy, won't it?

Here is my class that I am talking about:

```
/**
 * Allows for logcat output to be turned off centrally by switching the value of
 * a boolean variable for Store builds
 */
public class JKLog {

    /**
     * Set to false for Google Play Store builds
     */
    public static final boolean LOGGING_ALLOWED = true;

    /**
     * This tag will be used as the automatically passed first parameter to the custom log library used
     * Whenever we need to call the log methods only passing a message parameter
     */
    public static final String DEFAULT_LOGGING_TAG = "MyApp";

    private static final String ERROR_PARAMETER_IS_NULL_OR_EMPTY = "Parameter passed is either null or empty";

    public static void logDEvenWhenLoggingIsDisabled(String tag, String message) {
        if (tag != null && message != null) {
            Log.d(tag, message);
        } else if (message != null || !message.contentEquals("")) {
            Log.d(tag, ERROR_PARAMETER_IS_NULL_OR_EMPTY);
        }
    }

    public static void logEEvenWhenLoggingIsDisabled(String tag, String message) {
        if (tag != null && message != null) {
            Log.e(tag, message);
        } else if (message != null || !message.contentEquals("")) {
            Log.e(tag, ERROR_PARAMETER_IS_NULL_OR_EMPTY);
        }
    }

    public static void d(Object message) {
        if (message != null) {
            d(DEFAULT_LOGGING_TAG, message.toString());
        } else {
            d(DEFAULT_LOGGING_TAG, ERROR_PARAMETER_IS_NULL_OR_EMPTY);
        }
    }

    public static void e(Object message) {
        if (message != null) {
            e(DEFAULT_LOGGING_TAG, message.toString());
        } else {
            e(DEFAULT_LOGGING_TAG, ERROR_PARAMETER_IS_NULL_OR_EMPTY);
        }
    }

    public static void i(Object message) {
        if (message != null) {
            i(DEFAULT_LOGGING_TAG, message.toString());
        } else {
            i(DEFAULT_LOGGING_TAG, ERROR_PARAMETER_IS_NULL_OR_EMPTY);
        }
    }

    public static void w(Object message) {
        if (message != null) {
            w(DEFAULT_LOGGING_TAG, message.toString());
        } else {
            w(DEFAULT_LOGGING_TAG, ERROR_PARAMETER_IS_NULL_OR_EMPTY);
        }
    }

    public static void d(String tag, Object message) {
        if (message != null) {
            d(tag, message.toString());
        } else {
            d(tag, ERROR_PARAMETER_IS_NULL_OR_EMPTY);
        }
    }

    public static void e(String tag, Object message) {
        if (message != null) {
            e(tag, message.toString());
        } else {
            e(tag, ERROR_PARAMETER_IS_NULL_OR_EMPTY);
        }
    }

    public static void i(String tag, Object message) {
        if (message != null) {
            i(tag, message.toString());
        } else {
            i(tag, ERROR_PARAMETER_IS_NULL_OR_EMPTY);
        }
    }

    public static void w(String tag, Object message) {
        if (message != null) {
            w(tag, message.toString());
        } else {
            w(tag, ERROR_PARAMETER_IS_NULL_OR_EMPTY);
        }
    }

    public static void d(String tag, String message) {
        if (LOGGING_ALLOWED && tag != null && message != null && !message.contentEquals("")) {
            Log.d(tag, message);
        } else if (LOGGING_ALLOWED && (message == null || message.contentEquals(""))) {
            Log.d(tag, ERROR_PARAMETER_IS_NULL_OR_EMPTY);
        }
    }

    public static void e(String tag, String message) {
        if (LOGGING_ALLOWED && tag != null && message != null && !message.contentEquals("")) {
            Log.e(tag, message);
        } else if (LOGGING_ALLOWED && (message == null || message.contentEquals(""))) {
            Log.e(tag, ERROR_PARAMETER_IS_NULL_OR_EMPTY);
        }
    }

    public static void i(String tag, String message) {
        if (LOGGING_ALLOWED && tag != null && message != null && !message.contentEquals("")) {
            Log.i(tag, message);
        } else if (LOGGING_ALLOWED && (message == null || message.contentEquals(""))) {
            Log.i(tag, ERROR_PARAMETER_IS_NULL_OR_EMPTY);
        }
    }

    public static void w(String tag, String message) {
        if (LOGGING_ALLOWED && tag != null && message != null && !message.contentEquals("")) {
            Log.w(tag, message);
        } else if (LOGGING_ALLOWED && (message == null || message.contentEquals(""))) {
            Log.w(tag, ERROR_PARAMETER_IS_NULL_OR_EMPTY);
        }
    }

} // End of Class
```

Comment: depends i guess, it may be better to implement the class as abstract for example if you're reusing the same fragment container for every fragment.

Comment: if your using any resource related things(like xml files) in that class then u need to make it as library project otherwise you can use thta class directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by making a library of this class. And when you get more and more common components, you can add new classes to that library. A single class, that's how most non-proeminent libraries start.

Comment: I will edit my answer to show you the class and the possible extension I had in mind for it

Comment: Would that be really needed? I believe you should trust your own judgement on it.

Comment: So you are saying that there ARE libraries out there that consist of one class only?

Comment: Yes. One of the best example was the `SwingWorker` class used by many Swing developers in Java versions 1.2 -> 1.5 before it was adopted by Sun in Java 1.6. Ok, that's out of Android, but still, it's an example.